# Trouble combing two SQL statements with a running total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble combining these two SQL Statements:

```
SELECT A.PayeeID, A.Date, Sum(A.PermCashAmt), A.Currency, Year(A.Date) as Year_Occured 
FROM PermCashIn as A 
GROUP BY A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date)
```

AND

```
SELECT B.PayeeID, B.Date, Year(B.Date) as Time_Period, 
  (SELECT SUM(C.PermCashAmt) 
   FROM PermCashIn as C 
   WHERE C.Date <= B.Date And Year(C.Date)=Year(B.Date) 
   And C.PayeeID = B.PayeeID) as RunningTotal 
FROM PermCashIn as B 
GROUP BY B.Date, B.PayeeID, Year(B.Date) 
ORDER BY B.PayeeID, B.Date
```

I think the answer is this:

```
SELECT A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date) as Year_Occured, Sum(A.PermCashAmt), (
    SELECT SUM(C.PermCashAmt)
    FROM PermCashIn as C
    WHERE C.Date <= B.Date And Year(C.Date)=Year(B.Date) 
    And C.PayeeID = B.PayeeID
   ) as RunningTotal 
FROM PermCashIn as B 
INNER JOIN PermCashIn as A 
  ON (B.Date = A.Date) 
  AND (B.PayeeID = A.PayeeID) 
GROUP BY A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date) 
ORDER BY A.PayeeID, A.Date
```

But I get the Error

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column
>   'PermCashIn.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column
>   'PermCashIn.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Column
>   'PermCashIn.PayeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

## Error Type:

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException

I think I am using the GROUP BY clauses correctly and I am wondering if the problem is in my running total.  Please help this is my first project using SQL server.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using. The query you have here has been referred to as a triangular join and has some very serious performance issues. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/

Comment: If you want to avoid a major re-write, why not just try adding the columns indicated by the error message to the GROUP BY clause?   Actually, I bet if you change the running total subquery to use `A.Date` and `A.PayeeID` instead of their equivalent columns in B, the error will probably go away.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
SELECT A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date) as Year_Occured, Sum(A.PermCashAmt), 
Sum((
    SELECT C.PermCashAmt
    FROM PermCashIn as C
    WHERE C.Date <= B.Date And Year(C.Date)=Year(B.Date) 
    And C.PayeeID = B.PayeeID
   )) as RunningTotal 
FROM PermCashIn as B 
INNER JOIN PermCashIn as A 
  ON (B.Date = A.Date) 
  AND (B.PayeeID = A.PayeeID) 
GROUP BY A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date) 
ORDER BY A.PayeeID, A.Date
```

(not sure if the double parenthesis are needed or not...)

Answer (score 0):

So instead of using the self-join for the last select statement I used it in the subquery. The answer was obvious I cannot believe I did not see it

```
SELECT A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date) as Year_Occured, 
(SELECT Sum(B.PermCashAmt)
FROM PermCashIn as B 
WHERE B.Date = A.Date and B.PayeeID = A.PayeeID AND B.Currency = A.Currency) + 
ISNULL((SELECT Sum(AdjB.PermCashAmt)
FROM PermCashInAdjust as AdjB 
WHERE AdjB.Date = AdjA.Date AND AdjB.PayeeID = AdjA.PayeeID AND AdjB.Currency = AdjA.Currency),0)
as MonthTotal, 
(SELECT SUM(C.PermCashAmt)
FROM PermCashIn as C
WHERE C.Date <= A.Date And Year(C.Date)=Year(A.Date) And C.PayeeID = A.PayeeID AND C.Currency = A.Currency)  +  
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(AdjC.PermCashAmt)
FROM PermCashInAdjust as AdjC
WHERE AdjC.Date <= AdjA.Date And Year(AdjC.Date)=Year(AdjA.Date) AND AdjC.PayeeID = AdjA.PayeeID AND AdjC.Currency = AdjA.Currency),0) as RunningTotal
```

FROM PermCashIn as A LEFT JOIN PermCashInAdjust as AdjA ON (A.PayeeID = AdjA.PayeeID) AND (A.Date = AdjA.Date)
GROUP BY A.PayeeID, A.Date, A.Currency, Year(A.Date), AdjA.PayeeID, AdjA.Date, AdjA.Currency